# how to match words in a string using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like this

```
test = "row-even row-dd testing"
```

Now i want to only get words that starts with `row-` .

I used test =~ /row-(.*)/
but it kept returning me 0.anyidea how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 is the starting position of the pattern found.

Try this instead:

```
puts test.scan(/row-\w+/)
```

Comment: thanks, i can now add .uniq at the end to get only the unique characters

Answer (score 2):

```
r = /
    (?<=\A|\s)   # match start of string or space in a positive lookbehind
    row-         # match string 'row-'
    [[:alpha:]]+ # match one or more letters
    (?=\s|\z)    # match a space or end of string in a positive lookahead
    /x           # free-spacing regex definition mode

"row-even row-dd testing".scan(r)    #=> ["row-even", "row-dd"]
"borrow-even row-dd testing".scan(r) #=> ["row-dd"]
"row-even row-dd1 testing".scan(r)   #=> ["row-even"]
```